# Why is it no longer possible to make posts, links or photos in Facebook visible to certain friend lists only?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I used to be able to do this with the old profile. Since Facebook upgraded me to the new profile I cannot select friend lists in the privacy settings or even below single posts anymore although the lists all still exist and older posts/settings have not been affected...

For now I can only type in single names of people I want to be able to see a certain post/link/photo or make it visible to everyone, which is extremely bothering...

Maybe it is a bug, I wrote to Facebook help about this a few days ago but have yet to get a response...

Answer (score 6):

The settings are still there when you post.

In the case below I have a list called Locked and I allow everyone except those in that list.

[image: Publisher showing Privacy Setting]

You can always edit this by clicking on it.

[image: Editing the Privacy setting]

From there the same way that you will reference a friend, is the same way you would reference a list. Just type the list name. Below I used it in the hide list, but you could do the same with "Make this visible to" , just select "Specific People"

[image: Updated Settings showing the Locked List]

So you could say the "These people" could have been a bit more descriptive and said "These people and lists"

For older posts there is a little lock icon that shows the privacy settings for that particular item.

Comment: Any idea if this can be achieved [automatically for a certain set of old posts with Facebook's API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555091/does-the-facebook-api-allow-for-automated-changes-to-old-post-visibility)